# Referencing previous fields when constructing new structure

Tags: lean, beginner

Let's say I have a simple structure

```
structure foo : Type :=
  (a : ℕ)
  (b : list (fin a))
```

when defining the field `b` I can reference `a`. If I try to define a function to construct new foo's like so

```
def bar (p : foo) : foo :=
{ a := p.a + 1,
  b := list (fin a)
}
```

where I tried to reference the `a` I constructed on the first line,
which gives me the error `unknown identifier 'a'`.

Is there a way to use previously constructed fields like this?

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in `bar`: going by the definition of `foo`, `b` is supposed to be a list of elements, not the type `list (fin a)` itself, right?

Comment: Yes you're right, I just quickly constructed a simple example of what I was trying to illustrate what I wanted to do, that's why it doesn't make a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't, and I don't think it would be a good idea to change that because it could easily lead to unintentional shadowing. The only language I know that has recursive record instantiation, Nix, has a dedicated syntax for that for presumably exactly that reason: `rec { ... }`. In Lean, you should use a `let` binding instead.